# Trying to create a VBA to paste an Excel table into Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I've created a macro to paste an Excel table into word but the macro isn't working, and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. See code below for reference.

I've also checked the "Reference" --> "Microsoft Word 16.0 Object Library"

TIA!

```
'
' CreateLabels Macro

Dim objWord
Dim objDoc
Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Open("C:\Users\username\Desktop\New Template.doc")
Dim x As Workbook
 
'Open Excel and Copy labels
    Set x = Workbooks.Open("Excel file path")
 
    With x.Sheets("Receiving Labels")
        LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With
    x.Sheets("Receiving Labels").Range("A1:E" & LastRow).Copy

With objDoc.Paragraphs(objDoc.Paragraphs.Count).Range
   'All formatting goes here
   .Paste
   .Font.Name = "Calibri"
   .Font.Color = wdColorBlack
   .Font.Bold = False
   .Font.Italic = False
   .Font.Allcaps = False
   .Font.Size = 8
End With
objWord.Visible = True
 
End Sub
```

Comment: What specifically is "not working"?

Comment: If it's an actual table you want to copy, perhaps try .PasteExcelTable instead of .Paste?
Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.selection.pasteexceltable

Comment: Your code works for me... so like @BigBen asked. "What specifically is not working"?

Comment: Could it be that you have macros disabled in Word?
What is not working, is the `C:\Users\username\Desktop\New Template.doc` opening? Is the data not being pasted?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Sub ExcelToWord()

'PURPOSE: Copy/Paste An Excel Table Into a New Word Document
'NOTE: Must have Word Object Library Active in Order to Run _
  (VBE > Tools > References > Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library)
'SOURCE: www.TheSpreadsheetGuru.com

Dim tbl As Excel.Range
Dim WordApp As Word.Application
Dim myDoc As Word.Document
Dim WordTable As Word.Table

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  Application.EnableEvents = False

'Copy Range from Excel
  Set tbl = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet1.Name).ListObjects("Table1").Range

'Create an Instance of MS Word
  On Error Resume Next
    
    'Is MS Word already opened?
      Set WordApp = GetObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If MS Word is not already open then open MS Word
      If WordApp Is Nothing Then Set WordApp = CreateObject(class:="Word.Application")
    
    'Handle if the Word Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "Microsoft Word could not be found, aborting."
        GoTo EndRoutine
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0
  
'Make MS Word Visible and Active
  WordApp.Visible = True
  WordApp.Activate
    
'Create a New Document
  Set myDoc = WordApp.Documents.Add
  
'Copy Excel Table Range
  tbl.Copy

'Paste Table into MS Word
  myDoc.Paragraphs(1).Range.PasteExcelTable _
    LinkedToExcel:=False, _
    WordFormatting:=False, _
    RTF:=False

'Autofit Table so it fits inside Word Document
  Set WordTable = myDoc.Tables(1)
  WordTable.AutoFitBehavior (wdAutoFitWindow)
  
EndRoutine:
'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```